# Rails Nested Joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join

Manufacturer

```
has_many :product
```

Product

```
has_many :part
```

PartsRequest

```
belongs_to :part
belongs_to :manufacturer
```

I am trying to do something in PartsRequest
e.g. Manufacturer A is trying to request for Parts from Manufacturer B

```
scope :incoming_requests, lambda { |manufacturer_id|
    joins(:part).joins(product).where("product.manufacturer_id = ?", manufacturer_id)
}
```

How do I join to parts, then from parts join with products?

Comment: Are you just looking for `joins(:part => :product)` or is it more complex than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scope :incoming_requests, lambda{|mid| joins(:part => :product).where(:product => {:manufacturer_id => mid}) }
```